# html anchor overlaps thumbnail/ creates white stripes under images

Tags: html, css, anchor

I have created an unordered list with my thumbnails tagged in it. Now (as Firebug tells me) the anchor tag is overlapping my thumbnails creating white stripes under my images. This is my code so far:

html:

```
    <div class="wrapper">
        <ul class="masonry">
           <li class="item">
              <a class=lightbox" href="1.jpeg">
                 <img alt="1.jpeg" src="thumb/1.jpeg">
              </a>
           </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
```

css:

```
.wrapper{
  width:90%;
  margin: auto;
  padding: 20px;
}
.masonry {
  column-count: 4;
  -moz-column-count: 4;
  column-gap: 0.5em;
  -moz-column-gap: 0.5em;
  -webkit-column-gap: 0.5em;

}
.item{
  background: #eee;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0 0 0.5em
  box-sizing: border-box;
  moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  webkit-box-sizing: border-box;

}
.item a{
  margin: 0;

}
.item img{
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0;

}
```

[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tpnsO.png)

You can see the problem live on [my homepage](http://ti-sign.ch/bewerbung)

Comment: Hi and welcome to SO.  FYI, your page also looks very different under chrome.  You might use both firefox and chrome to triangulate the problem...

Answer (score 1):

set `display: block` on `.item img`

see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5804278/636077)

Answer (score 0):

Add `line-height: 0;` to `.item img`.

The white strip results from the space for the descenders of letters - the image is put on the baseline, that space is left available, but `line-height: 0;`  makes it disappear.